# GCM does not send message to notification_key & returns with an empty response body

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

We're using notification_key to group multiple devices. Since yesterday we're unable to send a message to a notification_key. The GCM endpoint returns with status 200 but the response body is empty. The GCM diagnostics inside Google Play shows that no message has been sent to the device and we additionally checked that the message does not arrive at the device.

However, sending a message to a single registration_id (one of which is managed by notification_key) works as expected.

We haven't touched the GCM related code on our side and it was working as expected the days before. I would like to know if this error is known and if other apps are affected as well. Also happy to hear from Google if they were any changes in the last few days.

Comment: Can you post your full HTTP request body? It is also possible that your device group contains no device. If there is no device in your device group anymore, your message sending request will return you an empty body with status 200.

Comment: It is also possibly a same issue posted in the GCM GitHub page: https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/118

Comment: Thanks for the links @ztan. The issue is now resolved for us. It was an issue on Google's side, see also my post in the related Google Groups thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-gcm/lQ_HFJfXM34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by Google. This is the answer I got from the Google Group thread I've created for this issue:

> Hi Andreas,
>
> We had a recent issue in the send API, affecting a subset of the
>   notification_key requests. That issue should be fixed now.
>
> Please try again. If the API is still not working for you please
>   report back using:
>   https://support.google.com/code/contact/gcm_dev_support
>
> Thanks,
>   - Diego